# Compilation failing while using vue-select

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, vue-cli, vue-select

I am trying to create a simple vueJs project, and compile it with thethe help of webpack/babel. However upon running *npm run dev* to compile the project and start the vue server, I am getting that compilation of the Select.vue template has failed(the Select.vue which gets installed upon installing vue-strap), below is the exact error that is loading up on my local port:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-5f7db264","hasScoped":true,"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./node_modules/vue-strap/src/Select.vue
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) 
  Error compiling template:

  <div v-el:select :class="classes">
    <div class="form-control dropdown-toggle"
      :disabled="disabled || !hasParent"
      :readonly="readonly"
      @click="toggle()"
      @keyup.esc="show = false"
    >
      <span class="btn-content" v-html="loading ? text.loading : showPlaceholder || selected"></span>
      <span v-if="clearButton&&values.length" class="close" @click="clear()">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <select v-el:sel v-model="value" v-show="show" name="{{name}}" class="secret" :multiple="multiple" :required="required" :readonly="readonly" :disabled="disabled">
      <option v-if="required" value=""></option>
      <option v-for="option in options" :value="option[optionsValue]||option">{{ option[optionsLabel]||option }}</option>
    </select>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <template v-if="options.length">
        <li v-if="canSearch" class="bs-searchbox">
          <input type="text" placeholder="{{searchText||text.search}}" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"
            v-el:search
            v-model="searchValue"
            @keyup.esc="show = false"
          />
          <span v-show="searchValue" class="close" @click="clearSearch">&times;</span>
        </li>
        <li v-if="required&&!clearButton"><a @mousedown.prevent="clear() && blur()">{{ placeholder || text.notSelected }}</a></li>
        <li v-for="option in options | filterBy searchValue" :id="option[optionsValue]||option">
          <a @mousedown.prevent="select(option[optionsValue],option)">
            <span v-html="option[optionsLabel]||option"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark" v-show="isSelected(option[optionsValue])"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </template>
      <slot></slot>
      <div v-if="showNotify && !closeOnSelect" class="notify in" transition="fadein">{{limitText}}</div>
    </ul>
    <div v-if="showNotify && closeOnSelect" class="notify out" transition="fadein"><div>{{limitText}}</div></div>
  </div>

  - name="{{name}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
  - placeholder="{{searchText||text.search}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
  - invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in

    options | filterBy searchValue

  Raw expression: v-for="option in options | filterBy searchValue"


 @ ./node_modules/vue-strap/src/Select.vue 11:0-220
 @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

I am also attaching my main.js and App.vue file, into which I am calling the Select.vue component:

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header></app-header>
        <v-select v-model="selected" :options="['Vue.js','React']"></v-select>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/header.vue'
import select from '../node_modules/vue-strap/src/Select.vue'
import Footer from './components/footer.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        'app-header': Header,
        'app-footer': Footer,
        'v-select': select,
    },
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I wonder why I am getting this error. I originally had this error in another project too, but let it go because I thought it might be due to the old versions of dependencies that I was using there. But in this project I am using the latest ones, still it is not compiling. Also, the header and footer are working fine, no problem in them. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i think its from vue 1.x ?

Comment: Hi Estradiaz. It's vue 2.9. I'm sorry, but I fail to understand how v-for is related to my question. I am trying to build a dropdown using vue-select. The codepen here https://codepen.io/sagalbot/pen/NpwrQO has similar code, and is working fine there. I wonder what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors explain it:

```
- name="{{name}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
- placeholder="{{searchText||text.search}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
- invalid expression: Unexpected identifier in

  options | filterBy searchValue

Raw expression: v-for="option in options | filterBy searchValue"
```

1. replace `name="{{name}}"` with `:name="name"`
2. replace `placeholder="{{searchText||text.search}}"` with `:placeholder="searchText || text.search"`
3. `filterBy` is deprecated - [try replacing what you're iterating over with a computed method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Replacing-the-filterBy-Filter)

Comment: Hi willianderson. Thank you for looking into this. The errors are gone, but the v-select is not showing up on my html. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

From what you say and the code shown in the error, you are using this library:
https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap

This library is not mantained anymore and more importantly not compatible with Vue 2.9 that you are apparently using.

You can try to use [this alternative fork](https://github.com/wffranco/vue-strap) that should be compatible with Vue 2, but keep in mind that you may need to change your codebase.

Comment: Hi gere. Thank you for looking into this. I didn't know that vue-strap was not supported with Vue 2.9. But I fail to understand why upon creating a new project with vue-cli, the package.json contains vue-strap? Shouldn't they have removed it if it is no longer supported?

Comment: I tried using the alternate vue-strap, but now I am facing these errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60080825/v-select-component-not-loading-into-html?noredirect=1#comment106261442_60080825 .