# v-select component not loading into HTML

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create a basic site, where I need to select options from a dropdown menu. I am using the Select.vue from the vue-strap library to implement the same. However, the v-select component in not loading onto the html. Given below is the App.vue which inherits Select.vue from vue-strap:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header></app-header>
        <v-select v-model="selected" :options="['Vue.js','React']"></v-select>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/header.vue'
import select from '../node_modules/vue-strap/src/Select.vue'
import Footer from './components/footer.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        'app-header': Header,
        'app-footer': Footer,
        'v-select': select,
    },
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Given below are the errors that I am getting onto the web console:
[image]

I am unable to resolve these errors. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where are you defining `selected` in `v-model="selected"`?

Comment: Hi Brahim. Thanks for looking into this. selected is a computed property in the Select.vue. Do I need to include _v-model="selected"_ ? I thought that because Select.vue is a part of the library, I can directly use it without any modifications.

Comment: you're using it without defining it

Comment: I wonder how this has happened. I haven't touched that file.

Comment: `selected` should be defined in data object like `data() { return {selected:null}}`

Comment: It's is not throwing another error: _The computed property "selected" is already defined in data_ . Here's the link to the Select.vue file I am talking about: https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Select.vue

Answer (score 0):

:options="['Vue.js','React']"

Above line can be a big problem, since you are passing the static data and not assigning any variable you don't have to use :

: this actually a binding operator you should only use this when you are binding option to some variable

For eg:

```
data(){
return{
options:[['Vue.js','React']]
}

}
```

now inside your vue file, you can add

```
<v-select v-model="selected" :options=options></v-select>
```

If you dont want to declare variable then you can remove :

```
 <v-select v-model="selected" options="['Vue.js','React']"></v-select>
```

Always make sure whatever you are passing to the component is declared inside the data

If you want to use computed make sure you declare it upfront before using it